# Multiple choice quiz that retrieves data from a database - how to make values from database go into random radiobuttons?

Tags: database, vb.net

I am creating a multiple choice quiz that gets its questions and answers from an access database.

So far I have managed to connect the database to the form and input the questions into the radiobuttons.

I can mark the question but so far I haven't figured out how to randomise the database fields to go into different radiobuttons. I don't want the actual answer being in the same radiobutton throughout the loop of the questions.

Attached is a picture of the form [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMnPX.png)

below is the code I use.

button1 is the next button

button2 is the back button

button3 is the save button

button4 is the return to last form button

button5 is the start button

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
      " Data Source= C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Normalised Database.accdb"

    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim no As Integer
    Dim q(no) As String
    Dim quesnum As Integer
    Dim answer As String
    Dim selected As String
    Dim score As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        no = InputBox("Input the number of questions you want. You can choose from 1 to 10.")
        Label1.Hide()
        Label2.Hide()
        Label3.Hide()
        RadioButton1.Hide()
        RadioButton2.Hide()
        RadioButton3.Hide()
        RadioButton4.Hide()
        Button1.Hide()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button3.Hide()
        Button4.Hide()

        For i = 1 To no
            question()
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub question()
        cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
        cn.Open()

        quesnum = 1
        Label1.Text = "Question " & quesnum & " of " & no

        cm.CommandText = "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, CorrectAnswer FROM Question"
        cm.Connection = cn

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader

        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            Label2.Text = dr.Item("Question")
            RadioButton1.Text = dr.Item("Answer1")
            RadioButton2.Text = dr.Item("Answer2")
            RadioButton3.Text = dr.Item("Answer3")
            RadioButton4.Text = dr.Item("CorrectAnswer")

            dr.Close()
        End If
        cn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub mark()
        cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
        cn.Open()
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT CorrectAnswer FROM Question"
        cm.Connection = cn
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            answer = dr.Item("CorrectAnswer")
            dr.Close()

        End If
        cn.Close()

        If selected = answer Then score = score + 1
        MsgBox("score is " & score)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then selected = RadioButton1.Text
        mark()


    End Sub


    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Label1.Show()
        Label2.Show()
        Label3.Show()
        RadioButton1.Show()
        RadioButton2.Show()
        RadioButton3.Show()
        RadioButton4.Show()
        Button1.Show()
        Button2.Show()
        Button3.Show()
        Button4.Show()
        Button5.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am also having trouble looping through the questions so that different questions and answers show when the next and back buttons are pressed.

much help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: a) turn on option strict.  InputBox returns a string; you are assigning to an integer. b) your `question` method selects all cols and rows.  Build a table from it so you dont have to hit the database again to get the answer c) name your controls for us if not for you.  How are we supposed to know what Button5 or Button1 does?  d) pick random ones by choosing a random row in teh DataTable

Comment: Instead of hard coding a column to a radio buttons, why not read the answers to a List<String> or String[] array, shuffle the array, and only then applying it to the radio buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list - for example

```
Dim answerList As New List(Of String)
```

and add your query results to this - Like this

```
        answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("Answer1"))
        answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("Answer2"))
        answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("Answer3"))
        answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("CorrectAnswer"))
```

then this function to randomize the order of the list

```
Private Function RandomizeListOrder(answers As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    Dim answer2 As Integer
    Dim rnd As New Random
    'loop though each item in the list
    For answer1 As Integer = 0 To answers.Count - 1
        'pick a random answer
        answer2 = rnd.Next(0, answers.Count - 1)
        'If answer1 and answer2 are the same then skip the rest of the code
        'in the loop and go onto the next question
        If answer1 = answer2 Then
            Continue For
        End If
        'swap the questions over
        Dim temp As String
        temp = answers(answer1)
        answers(answer1) = answers(answer2)
        answers(answer2) = temp
    Next
    'return the list of answers
    Return answers
End Function
```

Like this

```
answerList = RandomizeListOrder(answerList)
```

then add each element of the list to a radio button

```
RadioButton1.Text = answerList(0)
RadioButton2.Text = answerlist(1)
RadioButton3.Text = answerList(2)
RadioButton4.Text = answerlist(3)
```

Oh - and listen to Plutonix - He is wise.

**Update**

Hopefully when the code is added to yours, it should look like this - I think. I tested the function on my PC and it seems to work fine. If there is still an error, it may be in your code somewhere.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
      " Data Source= C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Normalised Database.accdb"

    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim no As Integer
    Dim q(no) As String
    Dim quesnum As Integer
    Dim answer As String
    Dim selected As String
    Dim score As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        no = InputBox("Input the number of questions you want. You can choose from 1 to 10.")
        Label1.Hide()
        Label2.Hide()
        Label3.Hide()
        RadioButton1.Hide()
        RadioButton2.Hide()
        RadioButton3.Hide()
        RadioButton4.Hide()
        Button1.Hide()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button3.Hide()
        Button4.Hide()

        For i = 1 To no
            question()
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub question()
        cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
        cn.Open()

        quesnum = 1
        Label1.Text = "Question " & quesnum & " of " & no

        cm.CommandText = "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, CorrectAnswer FROM Question"
        cm.Connection = cn

        dr = cm.ExecuteReader

        Dim answerList As New List(Of String)

        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            Label2.Text = dr.Item("Question")

            answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("Answer1"))
            answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("Answer2"))
            answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("Answer3"))
            answerList.Items.Add(dr.Item("CorrectAnswer"))
            answerList = RandomizeListOrder(answerList)
            RadioButton1.Text = answerList(0)
            RadioButton2.Text = answerlist(1)
            RadioButton3.Text = answerList(2)
            RadioButton4.Text = answerlist(3)
            dr.Close()
        End If
        cn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub mark()
        cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
        cn.Open()
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT CorrectAnswer FROM Question"
        cm.Connection = cn
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            answer = dr.Item("CorrectAnswer")
            dr.Close()

        End If
        cn.Close()

        If selected = answer Then score = score + 1
        MsgBox("score is " & score)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then selected = RadioButton1.Text
        mark()


    End Sub


    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Label1.Show()
        Label2.Show()
        Label3.Show()
        RadioButton1.Show()
        RadioButton2.Show()
        RadioButton3.Show()
        RadioButton4.Show()
        Button1.Show()
        Button2.Show()
        Button3.Show()
        Button4.Show()
        Button5.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Function RandomizeListOrder(answers As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
        Dim answer2 As Integer
        Dim rnd As New Random
        'loop though each item in the list
        For answer1 As Integer = 0 To answers.Count - 1
            'pick a random answer
            answer2 = rnd.Next(0, answers.Count - 1)
            'If answer1 and answer2 are the same then skip the rest of the code
            'in the loop and go onto the next question
            If answer1 = answer2 Then
                Continue For
            End If
            'swap the questions over
            Dim temp As String
            temp = answers(answer1)
            answers(answer1) = answers(answer2)
            answers(answer2) = temp
        Next
        'return the list of answers
        Return answers
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: thank you, this is very useful and yes plutonix is super wise!

Comment: But when you say add your query results to this do you mean my database fields? like the answer1 field? and if so what would the format for that look like? thank you !

Comment: I've updated my answer for you - Though I'm not at my Visual Basic PC, so I can't make sure I'm exactly correct, but you get the idea

Comment: I get the gist of what its doing but i am rubbish at formatting so when i ran it i got this NullReferenceException was unhandled error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.- just on the "Next" in the randomize function

Comment: Ah.  Sorry.  My most regular. Mistake.  Try Dim answerList As New List(Of String)

Comment: i am still getting an error. I will paste my code at the bottom of my question, can you see if I have put everything in the correct place? thanks a million!

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer so that you can see my code added to yours. I presume the button click code that you have supplied is intentionally only part of the code as it only checks that RadioButton1 is selected

Comment: the randomise function works perfectly thank you! am having problems showing different questions but will make a new question about it

Comment: Well as your code is at the moment,  your loop doesn't pass any parameters to the question sub,  and the sub always sets question to 1, so you'll always get the first question

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer,  it helps other people to see that an answer works.  (and we both get reputation)  ;)

Comment: Sure. I'll have a look